# VsCode remove "tab" after the Ctrl+S

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I use the Vscode, I have some problem about space. I want to use `define` this type

```
#define EXAMPLE                           10
```

And than when I press the  `Ctrl+S` and save my project, Vscode removes all space in the workspace. I see this type:

```
#define EXAMPLE 10
```

How can I change this feature?

Comment: Is the word "EXAMPLE" in you first code line correct? It should it be `#define         10` instead? Also, which language is that or in other words which language is recognized by VS Code? Is it C/C++?

Comment: sorry it was typo mistake

Comment: Ok. And which language is it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open your `workspace` or `user settings` and look for the following settings:

`trimTrailingWhitespace`

`editor.trimAutoWhitespace`

Set one or both to `false`.

If that does not work: Do you use any linter extension that could cause this behaviour?

Comment: I wonder why this was marked as accepted. I don't think this is related to this specific issue, which is about spacing in the middle of a line